# php preg_match_all numbers in parentheses

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all, numeric

I am trying to load a remote website and get all numbers that are inside of parentheses. But what ends up happening is it only matches the last value.

Is my regex wrong? Am I using the correct flags?

I have added the example of what it should match on in the second $html variable.

```
    //$html = file_get_contents("http://example.com/test.html");

    $html = "(1234) (12) (1)  \r\n  (1346326)";
    preg_match_all("^[(\d)]+$^", $html, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
    print_r($matches);
    echo "<br>";
    foreach ($matches as $val) {
        echo "matched: " . $val[0] . "\n";

    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
preg_match_all("/\((\d+)\)/", $html, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER); 
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Comment: Thank you this worked. I had to adjust the foreach
`code`
  $html = "(1234) (12) (1)  \r\n  (1346326)";
  preg_match_all("/\((\d+)\)/", $html, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER); 
  print_r($matches[1]);  

  echo "<br>";
  foreach ($matches[1] as $val) {
      echo "matched: " . $val . "<br>\n";

  }`code`

Answer (score 0):

I see two possible issues.

First you are matching from start(^) to end($) it it will only match what fits exactly between start of line and end of line.

Second, you most likely want to use the /gs regex paramter to slurp it all in.

```
preg_match_all("/\b(\d+)\b/gs" ...
```

Comment: With PHP there is no "g" modifier. `preg_match_all()` is always global.